# YouTubeAndroidAPIDemo does not run

Tags: android, eclipse, api, youtube

i want to try the Youtube Api Demo, i downloaded and added my Api_key (eclipse) already and tried to run Demo, when i run the sample code  i have a screen with the list of sample pages but when i want to test any of this listed samples, i receive "unfortunately the Youtube Api has stopped"

What should i do, any help?, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the following block in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

and the following in **project.properties**

```
target=android-17
```

Comment: i did it but nothing changed.

Comment: There is no error in Logcat. It starts normal and i can see the start page of Application on my screen; where it says; "please select a demo; VideoWall, SimplePlayerView etc." When i choose one of them, the applicaion stops!

Comment: Once the app stops forcefully or due to some error, I guess there will be an entry in LogCat.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's still relevant..
But I had the same problem and I have found the solution.
it apears that once I checked in logcat I noticed that I got an Error saying "Developer_Key cannot be defined as null or empty"
so, in the DeveloperKey.java I changed it from null to a key.
how to get a key?

you can follow this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im69kzhpR3I

Comment: Well, just google "youtube developer key" if the video dies. there are lots of guides. hope my answer will be helpfull to someone, took me a while to understand that code error.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) to understand why your answer needs to be improved.