# trouble with running YoutubeAndroidAPIDemo app

Tags: android, api

I checked stackoverflow for similiar problems and didn't found anything.
so here's my problem, I'm building an android app and I need to use YouTube API.
I followed this guide:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

but I can't seem to run the Demo App.
the entire project is full of errors and I can't understand why,
all of the "R.id.blabla" items are having an error saying:
"blabla cannot be resolved or is not a field"

I checked those Questions - [Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea)

and : [YouTubeAndroidAPIDemo does not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919816/youtubeandroidapidemo-does-not-run)

tried everything there, didn't helped much.
I'm pretty sure I am missing something but I have no idea what.
anyone else encountered something like this before?
plz help :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, try deleting the: import R.java line, if it's there.

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot! worked just like u said it will.
problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**layoutfile.xml**

```
      <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/teacherName"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:background="#fff"
                android:padding="5dp" />
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="115dp" 
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progressBarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="Video Loading..." />
```

**TutorialVideoView.java**

```
public class TutorialVideoView  extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
{

    private VideoView videoView;
    private MediaController mController;
    private Uri uriYouTube;


    ProgressBar progressBar1;
    TextView progressBarText;

     String v_title,v_date,v_id,v_url,v_teacher;

        public static final String API_KEY = "Your API key";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorialvideo_view);


        progressBar1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBarText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.progressBarText);

        v_id="Your YouTube Video ID";

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);


    }
      @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

            /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
            player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
            player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

            /** Start buffering **/
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.cueVideo(v_id);
            }
        }

        private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPaused() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaying() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopped() {

            }

        };

        private PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdStarted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {

            }
        };


}
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer, even if it didn't help me that much. I really appriciate it !